# Delete site collection level managed property using powershell

Tags: search, powershell, site-collection, managed-property

I have a managed property seen at `Search Schema` of both Search Service Application and Site collection.

The one at Site Collection level does not have Refine and Sort attributes set to True, so I am inclined to use the one from SSA.

**However I would like to get confirmed on which one of it is ideal to use?**

Can PowerShell help in deleting site collection level managed property? if so what would be the snippet?